# Use converter on bound items in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

i have a combobox which is bound to a datatable column like this:

```
ComboBox.DataContext = DataDataTable;                
ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = DataDataTable.Columns["IDNr"].ToString();
```

The IDNr in the Column always starts with 4 letters followed with the ID Number (ex. BLXF1234) .
I need to display the items in Combobox without the Letters (i need 1234 to be displayed in the combobox).

So i wrote a converter :

```
class IDPrefixValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string s = value.ToString();
            if (s.Contains("BL"))
            {
                return s.Substring(4);
            }
            else
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

No, how can i tell the combobox to use the converter to display the items ?
i tried this in the Xaml:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IDPrefixValueConverter}}"
```

But still not working ...any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: mmm...still dont know where the error is ...

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` is a **path to a property** to display not even a binding. If you apply the converter there you achieve nothing.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway iam checking what should be formatting the combobox items !!!?

Comment: ok, any chance for a help on this ??

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can modify the `ItemTemplate` of the `ComboBox` and use your converter:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IDPrefixValueConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Each item is bound to the items in the `ItemsSource`. By using the converter in the binding you are able to perform the conversion you want.

Comment: Thank you, problem was binding the combobox in the code behind ...but this solved my problem..

Comment: Does this really apply the converter to any of the items in the list? I tried the code but it seems as if the converter is only used for the selected item.

Comment: @tabina: It works with a simple `ComboBox` like the one in my sample. Perhaps you have a more complex `ComboBox`? Here is answer to a question that seems to be the opposite of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8247049/98607