# Populate DataGridComboBoxColumn using integer fields and an enum as it's display name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, material-design-in-xaml

I receive a query from database containing an array of users and in the user class I have a byte field named `Role`. I want my `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to have 2 items. if `Role == 0` it's `"Member"` and if `Role == 1` it's `"Moderator"`.

**User.cs**

```
public enum UserRole
{
    Member,
    Moderator
}

public class User
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public User(int userId, string email, string password, string token, string nickname, byte role, uint coins, int power1, int power2, int power3, int power4, DateTime createTime, DateTime? lastLoginTime)
    {
        this.UserId = userId;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Token = token;
        this.Nickname = nickname;
        this.Role = role;
        this.Coins = coins;
        this.Power1 = power1;
        this.Power2 = power2;
        this.Power3 = power3;
        this.Power4 = power4;
        this.CreateTime = createTime;
        this.LastLoginTime = lastLoginTime;
        this.UserRole = (UserRole)role;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("userId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("nickname")]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("role")]
    public byte Role { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("coins")]
    public uint Coins { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("power1")]
    public int Power1 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("power2")]
    public int Power2 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("power3")]
    public int Power3 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("power4")]
    public int Power4 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("createTime")]
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lastLoginTime")]
    public DateTime? LastLoginTime { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn
  Header="Role"
  Width="100">
    <materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type ComboBox}, ResourceId=MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumnEditingStyle}}" >
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Role}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="UserRole"/>
        </Style>
    </materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle
</materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code and XAML that you should resolve.

- A data grid column is not part of the visual tree, which means relative source and element name bindings like your binding the `DataContext.Role` will not work.
- Your `UserRole` type is an `enum`, but you want to display its constant names in a combo box column as items to select from. The `ItemsSource` property expects an enumerable type which an enum is not.
- I assume that you bind an array or collection of `User`s to your data grid. That means the data context of your column is a `User` instance. In this case your combo box `ItemsSource` binding does not make sense, since you are trying to bind the data grid data context, which does not contain the current user and even if it did, the `Role` property is a `byte`, not an enumerable.
- You set the `DisplayMemberPath` to `UserRole`, but it will not work, because you want to bind your combobox to constants of the `UserRole` enum, which does not contain a property `UserRole`.
- Your `User` type contains both `Role` of type `byte`, as well as `UserRole` of type `UserRole`. It is unclear which property of both you want to use and what the other one is used for.
- Your enum type has the [underlying type `int`, which is the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum). If you use values internally as `byte` anyway, you might consider changing it to `byte`.
- You only set an editing style, but not a non-editing style, which will make the value pop-up when you enter edit mode and and hide it when you leave editing mode.
- You set the `DisplayMemberPath`, but I think what you really want to do is bind the `Role` property as selected item.

In the following I assume that you want to use the `Role` property of type `byte` for binding and that you want to display the constant names of the `UserRole` enum in your combo box column.

First, you have to create an enumerable of your enum constants. You could provide a collection in code, that you could bind to, but since it does never change and is currently only used in the data grid, you can [create it entirely in XAML using an `ObjectDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-an-enumeration?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) like this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="UserRoles" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
   <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      <x:Type TypeName="local:UserRole"/>
   </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Next, we need to create a converter that converts a `byte` to a `UserRole` and back.

```
public class UserRoleToEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (UserRole)System.Convert.ToByte(value);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (byte)(int)value;
   }
}
```

Now let us put it all together in a data grid and bind to the `Role` property.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <local:UserRoleToEnumConverter x:Key="UserRoleToEnumConverter"/>
      <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="UserRoles" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
         <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:UserRole"/>
         </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Role"
                                             IsEditable="True"
                                             Width="100">
         <materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type ComboBox}, ResourceId=MaterialDataGridComboBoxColumnEditingStyle}}" >
               <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
               <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserRoles}}"/>
               <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Role, Converter={StaticResource UserRoleToEnumConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
         </materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      </materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As I already mentioned above, since you only adapt the editing style, you column might not behave like you expect. I recommend you to not edit the style at all, but rather set the bindings on the column:

```
<materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Role"
                                       IsEditable="True"
                                       Width="100"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserRoles}}"
                                       SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Role, Converter={StaticResource UserRoleToEnumConverter}}"/>
```

This approach will work for your requirements, but using enum constants to display UI texts directly is bad. Think about localization and items with more than a single work. You would not display camel cased text. Going forward, maybe you should consider using a more flexible and robust solution.

Comment: It must feel nice to be that guy

Answer (score 1):

Because you already have a enum for casting the byte value from database, you just need a dedicated converted:

```
public class UserRoleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var enumValue = UserRole.Member;

        if (value is UserRole)
        {
            enumValue = (UserRole)value;
        }

        switch (enumValue)
        {
            case UserRole.Member: return "Member";
            case UserRole.Role: return "Moderator";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value that is produced by the binding target.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type to convert to.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="NotImplementedException"></exception>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please note that by looking at `CultureInfo` converter parameter you might localized your string if needed.

Another approach might be bind a `string` property of your ViewModel so the XAML and add the string conversion within the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do I use this within my xaml code ?

Comment: Please follow the post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448862/use-converter-on-bound-items-in-combobox that let you describe how to use a Converter when using DisplayMemberPath approach you used.